# Checkout/clone Bitbucket repo without using 'git' in a Powershell script

Tags: git, rest, powershell, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm currently writing a Powershell script that clones a Bitbucket repository branch. The script does some processing based on a JSON file and determines which branch and repo it should pull. I've looked through the Bitbucket REST API documentation and can't seem to find an example of pulling down a specific branch for a repo. Does anyone know if this is possible? Also, this script will be running on a machine without 'git' (and I can't install it on there either), so I cannot use standard 'git' commands.

Comment: So.. rewriting git in PowerShell?

Comment: I guess you could say that - specifically the checkout/clone portion.